# perl regex to append backslash to directory paths

Tags: regex, perl

My application accepts a number of paths from users that may or may not have terminated those paths with a backslash.  I would like to ensure that all paths are terminated with a backslash () so that I can append filenames to them for performing other various operations.  I've dug through a lot of questions here and haven't been able to find a solution so I hacked together the following:

```
    foreach my $path (@Path) {
      my $char = chop($path);
      if ($char ne '\\') {
        $path = $path . $char . '\\';
      } else {
        $path = $path . '\\';
    }
```

This is probably a pretty terrible way of doing it, but it works.  Can anyone provide me a regex alternative?

Comment: You should consider using a module for paths, such as  [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3A%3ASpec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path =~ s/(?<!\\)$/\\/;
```

`(?<!\\)` is a negative lookbehind which will cause the match to fail if the previous character is not a backslash, and the `$` is an end of string anchor.  So this regex will fail to match anything if the last character is a backslash, or it will match after the last character in the string if that character is not a backslash.  We then use a backslash as the replacement so if the regex matched we append a backslash to the end.

Comment: `s/\\?$/\\/` will do the same thing.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user2808297 What convinced you? The part where its less easy, less safe or less portable?

Answer (score 8):

Use [`File::Spec`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec) to build your paths. It is easier, and safer and more portable.

```
use File::Spec;
for my $path (@Path) {
    $path = File::Spec->catfile($path, "foo", "bar");
    # $path = "$path\foo\bar"  -- regardless of previous line ending
}
```